# How do I add a custom field to the "Products Inventory" tab in the WooCommerce settings?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-fields

I am searching for a way to add a new field to WooCommerce - Settings - Products - Inventory

See attached image:

[image: inventory]

---

After some research I believe I should make use of the `woocommerce_inventory_settings` filter hook, but I don't immediately have an idea how I can apply this in practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `woocommerce_inventory_settings` hook can be found (in WooCommerce 4.4.1) in [`class-wc-settings-products.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.4.1/includes/admin/settings/class-wc-settings-products.php) on line [`81`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.4.1/includes/admin/settings/class-wc-settings-products.php#L81)

So you could use

```php
// Add custom field: WooCommerce > Settings > Products > Iventory
function filter_woocommerce_inventory_settings( $settings ) {
    $settings[] = array(
        'title' => __( 'My title', 'woocommerce' ),
        'type'  => 'title',
        'desc'  => '',
        'id'    => 'product_inventory_custom_options',
    );
    
    $settings[] = array(
        'title'       => __( 'My message', 'woocommerce' ),
        'id'          => 'woocommerce_my_message',
        'type'        => 'text',
        'default'     => '',
        'class'       => '',
        'css'         => '',
        'placeholder' => __( 'Enter my message', 'woocommerce' ),
        'desc_tip'    => __( 'This is the message that appears when..', 'woocommerce' ),
    );
    
    $settings[] = array(
        'type' => 'sectionend',
        'id'   => 'product_inventory_custom_options',
    );

    return $settings;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_inventory_settings', 'filter_woocommerce_inventory_settings', 10, 1 );
```

---

To get the value elsewhere in code or on your website, use [`get_option( string $option, mixed $default = false )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/) - Retrieves an option value based on an option name.

```php
// Get message from field
$get_option = get_option( 'woocommerce_my_message' );
```